# Developing straight to the central repository, or not

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

So far I've resisted having a central repository that I push/pull the changes from my local repository to--I just develop straight to the central repository. I'm the only developer so there's nobody else to affect, plus the central repository is local so speed isn't an issue.

My local repository setup is quite complicated in itself, multiple clones with multiple named branches that I either pull or revert between for selective file sharing amongst many variations. Doing this extra step of pushing to a central repository could end up confusing me, plus it's another step in the workflow possibly not not needed.

This is my first time using a DVCS (Mercurial), and my first time developing solo with a VCS. I'm trying to get an idea if I might regret going down this path over developing in one repository and pushing to a central one.

Are their killer reasons for not doing what I'm doing?

Comment: My repository is still rather simple, but I'm committing to the central repo too and nowhere else for now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main killer reason for not doing what you're currently doing is that you already consider it as complex and that, whatever "central repository" you're talking about would bring confusion to you.

One of the big purpose of a VCS and that should guide your choice for one against the other is that it helps your development flow. As soon as your VCS start to be a global slow down, it's a sign that there is an issue, either with the choice of VCS, either with how you're using it.

I would suggest you to read questions and blog posts related to vendor branches as it seems that you'r trying to achieve such a thing with your local set of clones.

Comment: I like your thinking. The structure however is really as simple as it could be and works well. As days pass, I'm retraining my mindset from SVN and finding the new workflow absolute heaven compared to SVN days--finally no hindrance. I guess the complication came from arriving at the structure to start with.

So my question is really becoming about whether pushing my local commit repo out to another repo has benefits making the extra step worth it.

Comment: The only benefits I could see then are that: 1. Your central repository might be available from outside, while your local one is tied to your current computer; 2. It's a cheap way to have a backup of your repository.

Comment: Ok, I feeling more comfortable then. I actually do push to bitbucket but purely for backup as you say, rather than thinking of it as a central repository.